# MeeGo, booting from USB won't work

Tags: usb, boot, meego

I'm considering buying the new EEE PC X101 because it fits right into our needs. This new netbook, the version I'm interested in, runs on MeeGo though, so I wanted to have a look at this operating system before buying anything running on it.

So here I am, trying to boot MeeGo from a USB stick, created following [these instructions](https://meego.com/devices/netbook/installing-meego-your-netbook).

And I'm using this img: `meego-netbook-ia32-chrome-1.2.0.img`

I'm trying to boot it on my Core 2 Duo laptop, which I think is supported by MeeGo, but I have no luck. I get different errors every single time I try to boot.

Did anybody here try to boot MeeGo from a USB stick? Did it work? Did you need to do something special to get it working?

Comment: Oh damn, never mind, I just read this: ***Platforms with the GMA-500, Nvidia, or ATI graphics chipsets are not supported*** and of course, my laptop has an Nvidia on board...

Comment: Could you post that as an answer and accept it when possible? That way it comes up as an answered question.

Comment: will do, I thought I had to wait a few days before I could answer my own question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read through the instructions carefully you will come accros this:

*Platforms with the GMA-500, Nvidia, or ATI graphics chipsets are not supported*

... and of course, my laptop has an Nvidia on board.
In short, always read the instructions.

However, this bottles down to that I can't test MeeGo on a single computer in our house, and there are a few about. So, a very limited OS I'd say, which makes me a little afraid to buy a netbook that will depend on it! I could of course replace it with for instance Ubuntu, but with only 8GB (rumoured) SSD onboard, I'll get into trouble space-wise.